# Camunda ASYNC DELETE Process Instances API is not working

Tags: camunda

I have process instances to be deleted using /POST Async Delete API. We were able to get the response when calling this API but process instances count is not getting reduced. I there any mistake ? i am using camunda 7.11 and mysql 5.7.33 respectively.I am calling Camunda REST-API calls using node server. kindly help me to resolve this.

```
const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/delete`,
        headers,
        body:{  
            processInstanceIds:processInstanceIds,
            deleteReason : "Removed Process Instances via Script",
            "skipCustomListeners":true,
            "skipSubprocesses":true,
        },
        json: true
    };
request(options).then(data=>{
            return data;
        }).catch(e=> throw e;);
```

Comment: Which PI count are you looking at?

Comment: @rob2universe i am not looking for Process Instance count. but to delete process instances in bulk/batch wise.

Comment: So how are you validating the successful deletion? Can you still access the instance in afterwards? You wrote "but process instances count is not getting reduced"hence my question about the count.

Comment: i can verify from db using "select count(*) from act_ru_task" table. it is not reducing the count